# Jquery Horizontal 'locked' scroll on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im looking to create this effect here 
http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/examples/horizontalScroll.html#page3

The only problem is that for my specific use case I need this to be just one section on a normal page (not possible with this plugin).. so when the user scrolls to this section they get locked into a scroll that only goes horizontally for 5 slides then goes back into a normal scroll and so continues on down the page... I cant seem to find anything related to achieving this (that works).. very greatful for any pointers.

Comment: Yes this can be done with javascript, but have you tried anything at all, which will give us something to work with.

Comment: I would suggest looking into jQuery's `.scroll()` event https://api.jquery.com/scroll/. You have the scroll event that checks what a user is looking at on the page, by getting page positioning, and you can also check to see where the mouse is on the page. If the user is viewing the section and the mouse is inside that section move a slide in the section and prevent the default scroll action